# How to get KDL solver to solve for 6D, and not 3D only

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, ros-melodic, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to use KDL to calculate the inverse kinematics of a UR5 robot. I am using  something like this

```
constexpr std::size_t num_joints = 6;
// initial guess of joint angles 
KDL::JntArray joints_init;
joints_init.resize(num_joints);
// joints_init.data[0] = -0.5;
// joints_init.data[1] = -M_PI / 2;
// joints_init.data[2] = -M_PI / 2;
// joints_init.data[4] = M_PI / 2;
// joints_init.data[5] = 0.3;

/**********************************
 * target robot pose of tool w.r.t.
 *********************************/
KDL::Frame target_frame; // set desired end effector position

/***************************************************************************
 * pose corresponding to [0, -PI/2, -PI/2, 0, PI/2, 0] according to TF
 **************************************************************************/
KDL::Vector pos;
pos.data[0] = -0.675;
pos.data[1] = 0.1110;
pos.data[2] = 0.511;

// set desired end effector rotation
KDL::Rotation rot;
target_frame.p = pos;
target_frame.M = rot.RPY(-3.141, -1.568, -0.004);

KDL::JntArray joints_result;
joints_result.resize(num_joints);

std::cout << "Calling solver for IK!" << std::endl;
int status = ik_solver.CartToJnt(joints_init, target_frame, joints_result);
```

It seems that this works for the position only. I thought that the solver should solve for 6D also. Am I using this wrong? Does it only solve for position (3D) and not for the full pose(6D)?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351415/how-to-get-kdl-solver-to-solve-for-6d,-and-not-3d-only./) by [Pinknoise2077](https://answers.ros.org/users/47505/pinknoise2077/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2020-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In simple words 6d will have more flexibility on complex task and it will faster interms of calculating the position , velocity, I would suggest to go with ik fast from open rave ....or try the UR's Ur kinematics package to sort out the confusion

---

Originally posted by [Nitesh_j](https://answers.ros.org/users/54485/nitesh_j/) with karma: 65 on 2020-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pinknoise2077](https://answers.ros.org/users/47505/pinknoise2077/) on 2020-05-06**:
Thanks for the answer. I've figured a much better solution after being disappointed with how KDL IK solver performed. My solution was to switch to the symbolic version of the IK by using the ur_kinematics ROS package from https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot. It now works like a charm, returns a max of 8 solutions, and always work.

**Comment by [Nitesh_j](https://answers.ros.org/users/54485/nitesh_j/) on 2020-05-06**:
All the best